# Why can't an rpm use xterm?

Tags: x11, rpm

I made an RPM package that uses Xterm during its install. Whenever I installed the package that I made prior to packing into the RPM, the Xterm part of the install worked correctly. I am curious to why after packing into an RPM, when it tries to install using `yum` or `rpm`, it gives an error on the `xterm` line saying it can't find `xterm`? I am using this on Red Hat 6.5.

Comment: What do you mean by “installed the package that I made in the rpm prior to packing into the rpm”? Do you mean when you installed the **program** manually? What command did you use to install the RPM? What was the error message? Copy-paste.

Comment: I mean it was my own package so prior to packing it into an rpm installed it manually. I used the rpm -uvh and made it a repo and used yum install. The message was can not find Xterm @gilles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely interpretation of the question is that OP ran xterm (from a script perhaps) to perform part of the manual install.  But putting that functionality into an RPM `%prep`, `%pre` or `%post` scriptlet will not work because RPM runs as **root**, which has no access to the user's X display (unless that is opened up using `xhost`, and the script sets the `DISPLAY` variable).

That isn't recommended of course, but people do it anyway:

- [Cannot connect to X Server when running app with sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175611/cannot-connect-to-x-server-when-running-app-with-sudo)
- [ssh and sudo but no $DISPLAY](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241394/ssh-and-sudo-but-no-display)