# ssh and sudo but no $DISPLAY

Tags: ssh, x11, xorg, xforwarding

Usually I do this on ssh for getting a X application using `sudo su`

```
ssh -X server
```

OKI login

```
xauth list $DISPLAY
```

which returns to me

```
server/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  blablablablabla
```

Then I do

```
sudo su
xauth add server/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  blablablablabla
```

And after running an X application..I get it, it is correct.

The problem is on Centos7, I do

```
xauth list $DISPLAY
```

And it returns nothing. I try to add MIT magic cookies given by

```
xauth list
```

But of course it doesn't work.
The normal X-forwarding via ssh, without sudo works.

The settings of sshd are the same on 3 servers:

1. slackware *WORKS*
2. hpux      *WORKS*
3. centos7   ***NOT WORKING***

Comment: I try of course with selinux disabled,nothing to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution found.
An alternative method copied from this [blog](http://joelinoff.com/blog/?p=729)
Using this script

```
userfirst=sshloginuser
usersecond=sudoorsuuser

$usersecond@host$

    su - $userfirst -c 'xauth list' |\
         grep `echo $DISPLAY |\
             cut -d ':' -f 2 |\
             cut -d '.' -f 1 |\
             sed -e s/^/:/`  |\
         xargs -n 3 xauth add
```

Or simply
Logging as user1

```
xauth list
```

su or sudo su user2

```
xauth add OUTPUTOFXAUTHLIST
```

Answer (score 11):

Another solution is to merge the .Xauthority file of the current user with that of the root user.

1. `ssh user@host`
2. change the .Xauthority file permissions so that root also has access to it.
3. `sudo su - root`
4. `xauth merge /home/users/user/.Xauthority`

Test

```
gedit somefile.log
```

It should open a gedit window.

Answer (score 7):

to make the solution permanent you can modify the `.bashrc` file of the login user  adding

```
if [ -z "$XAUTHORITY" ]; then
    export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
fi
```

moreover you have to update your `sudoers` file adding the row

```
Defaults env_keep+="DISPLAY XAUTHORITY"
```

if root has read permissions on the login user's `.Xauthority` file you'll be able to use X applications.

Answer (score 4):

This might be an old post, but I solved this permanently linking (in server) my sudoer user .Xauthority file with the root one:

```
sudo ln -s /home/userWithPrivileges/.Xauthority /root/.Xauthority
```

This way I don't have to do anything else ever, I can now launch any GUI app with or without sudo.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple generic command:

```
sudo xauth merge /home/$USER/.Xauthority
```

This activates the root environment and merges the xauth info of the current (non root) user.

Another alternative, should prevent ownership problem reported in the comments on Slackware:

```
cat ~/.Xauthority | sudo xauth merge -
```

Comment: I tried this command and work, but has a little bad thing, the permissions of Xauthority files of user become of root. `ls -lhd /home/user/.Xauthority 
-rw------- 1 root root 318 2021-07-21 20:34  /home/user/.Xauthority`

Comment: Just checked on Ubuntu 20.04.  The ownership of the /home/$User/.Xautority is not modified.
The 'xauth merge ' is executed in the root environments and the file that is changed is /root/.Xauthority - as expected.

Maybe this behaves differently on other systems, but I could not recreate the problem on ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I confirm the problem on Slackware current `ls -lhd .Xauthority 
-rw------- 1 myuser myuser 63 2021-07-21 21:46 .Xauthority
sudo xauth merge /home/$USER/.Xauthority
ls -lhd .Xauthority 
-rw------- 1 root root 63 2021-07-22 21:50 .Xauthority`

Comment: Please check the alternative above that passes .Xauthorith via stdin. Should prevent ownership changes.

Comment: It fails `$ cat ~/.Xauthority | sudo xauth merge -
$ xmms
No protocol specified

** CRITICAL **: Unable to open display
$ ls -lhd .Xauthority 
-rw------- 1 root root 255 2021-07-27 01:04 .Xauthority`

Comment: I would suggest to check $DISPLAY is defined. Maybe copy .Xautority to a temp file and merging with the temp file. e.g.    

    cp /home/$USER/.Xauthority  /home/$USER/Xauthority.tmp ; sudo xauth merge /home/$USER/Xauthority.tmp ; rm /home/$USER/Xauthority.tmp

Answer (score 1):

The following allows any user to run X11 applications as root.

Run the following as the root user:

```
echo '\cp /home/$(logname)/.Xauthority Xauthority-tmp && xauth add $(xauth -f Xauthority-tmp list | tail -1)' >> /root/.bash_profile
echo 'rm -f Xauthority-tmp' >> /root/.bash_profile
```

Now you should be able to `sudo su -` from any user and start X11 applications.

Tested on Centos 8 (things like the default home dir may need to be adjusted and I believe $(logname) is not portable, but hopefully this helps someone!)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more what this does exactly, and what the security implications of using this are?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate this, then !

1- Add to your login user ~/.bashrc file the following :

```
xauth list |grep `uname -n` > /home/$(whoami)/.auth
echo $DISPLAY > /home/$(whoami)/.display
```

2- Add to the root user /root/.bashrc file the following :

```
loguser=$(logname)
xauth add $(cat /home/$loguser/.auth) 
export DISPLAY=$(cat /home/$loguser/.display)
```

Then when executing `su - root` the cookie and DISPLAY variable are loaded automatically.